# Is it possible Java Card supports NIO,like event-driven, reactor

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard, apdu

Is it possible [Java Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Card) supports NIO, like event-driven, reactor?Because when program send a apdu command can be block,then javacard can not process other apdu command

I would like to know how to send a apdu command in javacard program, and the program dont block, can process other apdu command.Or just wanna know is smartcard possible support nio.